# How to get point of click by Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have been developing some application, and I need to put Google Map on my site. I have made it using this code:

```
<?php
echo "<iframe width='425' height='350' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='http://maps.google.ru/maps?hl=ru&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=55.354135,40.297852&amp;spn=27.388971,86.572266&amp;t=h&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed'></iframe><br /><small><a href='http://maps.google.ru/maps?hl=ru&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=55.354135,40.297852&amp;spn=27.388971,86.572266&amp;t=h&amp;z=4&amp;source=embed' style='color:#0000FF;text-align:left'>Show map increased</a></small>";
echo "<form method='POST'><input type='text' /><input type='submit' /></form>";
?>
```

You can see that I use "form" also. It is important, because if user click by map then label from form should show coordinates of pointed clicked. But I don't know Java Script. Please, tell me, how can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to learn Javascript. Use the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/). [This example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple.html) is pretty close to what you want.